# How to check the toast message in Playwright?

Tags: xpath, message, playwright, toast, assertion

I am a newbie for automation tool, having no coding skills so please guide me as clearly as you can.

I am using Playwright (Typescript) to perform automation testing for a basic website and I have trouble to verify the "toast message".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpBQy.png)

1. I need to know the way to get Xpath of toast message for Playwright Typescript. Currently, the Developer gave me this: //ngb-alert//pre/text()'

But how to make sure that it is correct?

2. Was it exact when I used the assertion "toContainText" to check the toast message? If not, which one should be use for this case ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlNh3.png)

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of the site, and your code as text ([Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)). Thanks. Generally speaking, avoid XPaths. Prefer just about any other means of selection: text, role, title, test id, or CSS selector if you don't have a good visible attribute...

Comment: A well constructed xpath which is unique , flexible and dependent on user facing properties like text ,label etc are not definitely bad.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing locator with string. You need to use locator.innerText() to get text from the control and then need to verify.

```
await expect(locator.innerText()).toContainText('"Ikariam" was created successfully.');
```

Comment: So, no need to get Xpath of the toast message following your instruction, bro?

Comment: We need the xpath of toast message but expect should contain locator.innetText() so that you will get message of the toast.

Comment: So, the full command will be: await expect(//ngb-alert//pre/text().innerText()).toContainText('"Ikariam" was created successfully.');

 Just replace "locator" = "//ngb-alert//pre/text()" , is it right?

Comment: Tried it already as you said:
const locator = page.locator ('//ngb-alert//pre/text()');
await expect(locator.innerText()).toContainText('"Ikariam" was created successfully.');


and here is the error:

Error: toContainText can be only used with Locator object.

Comment: I think your xpath is wrong. Can you put xpath html element of toast message.

Comment: Thanks, bro. The Xpath was wrong. It should be not "text()", and finally I did it :)

Comment: This answer is helpful as contains useful info for the OP.